# Extremely slow browser in QGIS on one computer

Tags: qgis, qgis-browser

A while ago the browser in QGIS (Windows 10) slowed to a crawl. Clicking on any drive would display the “working” icon and render QGIS unusable for a minute or more. Clicking on a directory in that drive or on another drive similarly caused a lag of a minute or more. I installed QGIS on another computer and the browser behaves as it should.

I uninstalled all versions of QGIS on the first computer and removed all references to QGIS in the registry, and I deleted all user profiles in all user accounts. I installed the latest version of QGIS (3.36) and the slow browser behavior remains. I removed two external drives that aren’t on the second computer, but that changed nothing.

The browser in ArcGIS Pro behaves normally.

Any ideas?

Comment: You appear to have created two accounts. The other is https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/122005/bkepl. Please use the instructions in the [help] to merge your accounts.

Comment: Are there any mapped network drives in the browser?

Comment: There are several mapped drives in my network but I haven't mapped anything through QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Network drives that are not accessible or slow to access can slow the browser down. Supposedly fixed in more recent versions of QGIS but people still report problems.

Given that my GIS files are not on a network drive, the solution for me has just been to hide any external/network drives from the browser.

Right click on a drive and select **Hide from Browser** from the context menu.

[image]

Comment: Worth noting that there may be a new fix in an upcoming release of QGIS: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/51710

Comment: Since I have a couple external drives on my computer that the other doesn’t, I disconnected them, and hid network drives I never need to access. Browser still very slow. I installed the nightly build a few days ago, no difference. 

And I should add that the computer where the browser isn’t slow, I access as a remote session, and when I have been out of the office and connected through VPN, it’s also fine. I also tried with another user on my computer, still slow.

Comment: Sounds like you have a different issue to the current ones with workarounds or fixes. You may need to try and narrow things down as much as possible and then raise a bug with QGIS.